# Server isn't listed in "Add Servers" screen

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I´m trying to install the GlassFish Server in Eclipse Kepler IDE.
But, after installing the GlassFish Tools and Oracle Enterprise Pack the Eclipse is restarted but the Server isn't listed in *Add Servers* screen.

This problem occurs in Eclipse Kepler, Luna in Windows and Mac.

Comment: I edited your question so it is simpler to understand. Particularly the title was just copying the tags instead of explaining what the problem is.